# C, C++ or Objective-C code for converting JPEG images to TIFF format

Tags: c++, objective-c, c, image-processing, image-conversion

I am looking for a method to convert JPEG images to TIFF format then keep this TIFF image in base64 format.  The solution can be in C, C++ or objective C ... Please advise 
Thanks in advance

Comment: In case you didn't notice yet, this is not a demand and supply website, Tell us what you have done about the problem and we will help you depending on your approach

Comment: Sorry for the confusion .. i was able to encode the Jpeg image into base64 format .. now i need to convert the same into tiff base64 format.. if you want i can post the code as well

Comment: You need to read this, [Writing the perfect Question](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx)

Answer (score 5):

I've used ImageMagick before and it works well. I used RMagick, the bindings for Ruby, but they have [C++ bindings](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/magick++.php?ImageMagick=9u5uqa4i5qc9d84j9tlvegmkf1) too.  As far as keeping the tiff image in base64 format, you'll want another library like [libb64](http://libb64.sourceforge.net/).  The ImageMagick piece should be as simple as

```
#include <Magick++.h> 
#include <iostream> 
using namespace std; 
using namespace Magick;

int main(int argc,char **argv) 
{ 
  Image image;
  try { 
    image.read( "girl.jpg" );

    // convert to tiff
    image.write( "girl.tiff" ); 
  } 
  catch( Exception &error_ ) 
    { 
      cout << "Caught exception: " << error_.what() << endl; 
      return 1; 
    } 
  return 0; 
}
```

(Example modified from http://www.imagemagick.org/Magick++/Image.html)

To accomodate the in memory requirement, easy enough.

```
Image jpg = Image("/path/to/jpg");
jpg.magick("tiff");
Blob blob;
jpg.write(&blob);
```

I'll let you do the work of seeing how you'll get the bytes from the blob.

Comment: Thanks I82Much .. checking the lib

Comment: One more thing .. i can't write the image in systme which i Mac OS x , i need this conversion in memory ..

Answer (score 0):

libgd or ImageMagick should do the trick.